# jqgrid inline editing with errorfunc

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, jqgrid, inline-editing, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am trying to inline edit with jqgrid, where I am going to call a Spring controller, I need to do extra server side validations. If there are any server validation errors I need to send it back jqgrid via errorfunc, and user notified.

```
function saveRow(rowId) {
    saveparameters = {
            "url" : 'editcontroller',
            "successfunc" : function( response ) {

                alert('success');
                return true; 
            },
            "errorfunc": function (reponse) {
                alert('error');
                return true;
            }
        };
    jQuery('#myGrid').jqGrid('saveRow', rowId, saveparameters);
}
```

Could someone help me to understand what I have to write in spring controller to send server level validation errors to errorfunc. I Googled but couldn't find concrete example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, I just send HTTP header function 500 "Internal Server Error".
The errorfunc will catch it automatically.

header (HTTP/ 1.0 500 Error Message)